# A question about the existence of functional

Tags: functional-analysis

I am stuck on a question about the existence of functional.

**Question**

X is a Banach space and $f_n\in X^{*}$ satisfies that for any $x\in X$,  $\limsup_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)<\infty$ holds. 
**Prove**: There exist $f\in\ X^{*}$ such that $\liminf_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)\leq f(x)\leq\limsup_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$.

For this question I have only one idea, to use the Hahn-Banach theorem. But it seems not to work, so I would like to ask for some hints or answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Hints: Change $x$ to $-x$ in $\limsup_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)<\infty$ to see that $\liminf_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)>\infty$. This shows thet $(f_n(x))$ is bounded for each $x$ and Uniform Boundeness Principle shows that $\sup_n \|f_n\|<\infty$.

By Banach Alaoglu Theorem $(f_n)$ has  a weak* limit point $f$. Using definition of weak* convergence check that $f(x) \le \lim\sup f_n(x)$. The other inequality follows by just changing $x$ to $-x$.